# Saving an mp3 file to sd

Tags: android

i'm trying to download an mp3 file from an URL and save ut on the sd card in an music folder.
But no matter what I do it wont save it on the SD , it just downloads it and after while trying to find it it's no wher et obe found.

Here is my code in the async task class:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
try{
URL url = new URL(params[0]);
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)       url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.connect();

            File sd = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File file = new File(sd, "TestSongs.mp3");


            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            int totalsize = connection.getContentLength();
            int downloadSize = 0;

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bufferLength = 0;
            while((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0 , bufferLength);
                downloadSize += bufferLength;
                publishProgress("" + (int) ((downloadSize * 100) / totalsize));
            }
            outputStream.close();

        }catch(Exception e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you have set the appropriate permissions in the manifest? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

somewhere inside the your manifest, outside the `<application></application>` tag